# I'm trying to install a program (synergy) but it wont install

Tags: dpkg, software-installation

I'm trying to install synergy but when I type in

```
sudo dpkg -i synergy-1.4.15-Linux-i686.deb
```

it wont install. It just tells me that there isn't such file on the system.

Am I doing something wrong?

PS: I am new to ubuntu after using windows all my life..

Comment: Still doesnt work guys.

now I've tried QuickSynergy and that program doesnt work either.

but yes, I would preffer the original Synergy.

Comment: Exactly how do not install? What appears when you run `sudo dpkg -i synergy-1.4.15-Linux-i686.deb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First go into the directory where the .deb file is located,

```
cd /path/to/the/directory/which/contains/synergy-1.4.15-Linux-i686.deb
```

Then run the above deb file installation command,

```
sudo dpkg -i synergy-1.4.15-Linux-i686.deb
```

Comment: Still doesnt work guys.

now I've tried QuickSynergy and that program doesnt work either.

but yes, I would preffer the original Synergy.

Comment: did you go into the directory where the file was located?

Comment: Yes. Like this "cd /Desktop" if that didnt work I also tried "cd /Desktop/synergy-1.4.15-Linux-i686.deb"

Comment: open a new terminal then try this `cd ~/Desktop` and `sudo dpkg -i synergy-1.4.15-Linux-i686.deb` if the file was located on the desktop.

Comment: now it says: "dpkg: <danish>fejl under behandling af</danish> synergy-1.4.15-Linux-i686.deb (--install):
synergy:i386 1.4.15 (Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable with synergy:amd64 1.3.8-1ubuntu1 (Multi-Arch: no) which is currently installed"

Comment: you asked the question as how  install the synergy.deb file.If the installation of synergy from deb file gives error then ask it as an another question with that error report.

Comment: i think you already installed a synergy 64 bit version on your pc.

Comment: Yes. It's just weird cause my computer should be a 32-bit computer.

Answer (score 2):

you should type first in terminal  :

`cd` and the location of the .deb pacakge then type your code

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what tutorial are you following but `synergy` is in the repositories, you just have to

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synergy
```

Answer (score 0):

> sudo apt --fix-broken install

Above command fixed the issue for me. It installed the dependencies